# how to understand the enabler in C++ enable_if

Tags: c++, templates, traits

what is the meaning of below enable_if usage

```
template <
    typename R, typename F,
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<typename std::remove_cv<R>::type, any>::value>::type*& = enabler,
    typename... Args>
any call(F fn, Args&&... args) {
    return fn(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

especially `"type*& = enabler"`

Comment: @Brandon Write that as an answer.

Comment: missing definition of `enabler`, should probably be something like: `auto enabler = nullptr;`.

Answer (score 0):

It says: Enable `call` function if and only if non-const non-volatile `R` template parameter is of type `std::any` such that the parameter is a reference pointer to `enabler`. Otherwise, compiler error.

A reference pointer is a reference to a pointer. For example, in C++, we can do something like:

```
void func(int** ptr)
{
   *ptr = new int[100]; //ptr is a pointer to pointer.
}
```

but we can also do:

```
void func(int* &ptr)
{
    ptr = new int[100]; //ptr is a reference to a pointer.
}
```

Now for the sample usage of the above code..

```
#include <iostream>
#include <any>


void* enabler = nullptr;

template <
    typename R, typename F,
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<typename std::remove_cv<R>::type, std::any>::value>::type*& = enabler,
    typename... Args>
std::any call(F fn, Args&&... args) {
    return fn(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}


std::any func(int i)
{
    std::cout<<i<<"\n";
    return std::any(1);
}

void func2(int i)
{
    std::cout<<i<<"\n";
}

int func3(int i)
{
    std::cout<<i<<"\n";
    return 200;
}

int main() 
{
    //Return type is an std::any..

    auto rn = call<std::any>(func, 10);
    std::cout<<std::any_cast<int>(rn)<<"\n";

    //Return type is void and cannot be converted to std::any..
    //call<void>(func, 10); //Error here because void type is not `std::any` type..

    //Return type of `func3` is an integer.. `call` implicitly constructs an std::any from that..
    auto res = call<std::any>(func3, 20);
    std::cout<<std::any_cast<int>(res)<<"\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: in your example,i cannot see enabler to be used,just be Initialized.

Comment: @freyone That is true. Which seems like a mistake on the original author's part.

Comment: can you share the example how to use enabler

Comment: [This](https://godbolt.org/g/KRKSaz) is a better way to write the same thing. `enabler` is simply not used in your example.